# Rotating a particle at runtime in libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

My particle starts shooting upwards.

However if you shoot the "spell" with the particle to your right, I want to rotate the whole emitter -90 degrees so that it shoots rightward not upward.

How to do this.

This is my shooting right and the particle is exploding upwards which is weird so I want it to shoot at a -90 degree angle if I shoot right like in the following image

[image: example image]

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: @RohitGupta theres no code to show because I can't figure out any code to accomplish I will post an image of what is happening

Comment: I don't think this is supported.

Comment: Is there really no way to do this?! @Tenfour04

Comment: There is...you can submit a pull request to add the feature. :) There is already a method on ParticleEffect for flipping it, so you could follow that pattern for rotating it. I get around this by creating multiple versions of each effect in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Controller of an Effect and set the rotation to it. The controler itself is an Emitter. Moreover you can rotate the whole effect by setting the rotation on runtime.

Call the `Effect.rotate(Quaternion rotation);` [(See this)](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/fde893cec5448fdd09e778d1c103aac474950873/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/particles/ParticleEffect.java#L84) with the given quaternion which you need to update yourself in the actor and call the rotate. But the rotation itself is effected by the update of the the controller/emitter!

If you want to rotate a part of the Effect (like 1 or 2 emitters not all) Get the emitter by name (which you set in the GUI) with the `findController(string name)` [klick here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/fde893cec5448fdd09e778d1c103aac474950873/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/particles/ParticleEffect.java#L121) And set the rotation as above just to the [Controller](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/fde893cec5448fdd09e778d1c103aac474950873/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/particles/ParticleController.java#L90).

I would hardly recommend not to use a effect which shoots into one direction! Insead i would use a effect which has no movement into a direction, and move the Effect around, which has the same effect in the end but you can deside into which direction. Small example of what i mean:

```
public class SimpleRocket extends Firework {
    private ParticleEffect boom, thrust;
    private Vector2 direction;
    private boolean secondeffect = false;

    public SimpleRocket(FireworkTycoonMain main) {
        super(main);

        boom = new ParticleEffect();
        boom.load(Gdx.files.internal("effect/firework.p"),
                main.manager.getAtlas());
        thrust = new ParticleEffect();
        thrust.load(Gdx.files.internal("effect/goldregen.p"),
                main.manager.getAtlas());

        thrust.start();
    }

    public void init(float mass, float acceleration, Vector2 startdirection,
            int flytime) {
        this.thrust.setDuration(flytime);
        this.mass = mass;
        this.acceleration = acceleration;
        direction = startdirection;
        direction.nor();
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {

        final float alpha = direction.getAngleRad();

        final float y = (float) (Firework.GRAVITY * mass + acceleration
                * Math.sin(alpha) * delta * delta);

        final float x = (float) (acceleration * Math.cos(alpha) * delta * delta + wind);

        direction.x = x;
        direction.y = y;
        direction.nor();

        setPosition(getX() + x, getY() + y);

        boom.setPosition(getX(), getY());
        thrust.setPosition(getX(), getY());

        thrust.update(delta);
        boom.update(delta);

        if (thrust.isComplete() && !secondeffect) {
            main.sound.playPeng();
            boom.start();
            secondeffect = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha) {
        if (!boom.isComplete()) {
            boom.draw(batch);
        }
        if (!thrust.isComplete()) {
            thrust.draw(batch);
        }
    }
}
```

This example is old so it meight not be right on the newer libgdx versions.
[image]

[image]

If you do simmelar to a wide effect (not a point) it could look like your effect but you can move it around as you like.